# Драеный/драенный

Tags: орфография, причастия, нн

Как правильно? По идее, надо с одной ***н*** писать, так как *драить* — глагол несовершенного вида. Но в Викисловаре написано, что с двумя: [драить](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C).
Почему-с?

`Драеная/драенная палуба.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) **Качественное** значение прилагательного, можно заменить синонимом:

*Палуба и так **драеная,** блестит даже. Куда чище-то!* Но матросы, покосившись на начальника, вновь принялись ее драить.

(2) При наличии **зависимых слов** прилагательное переходит **в причастие** и обозначает законченное действие:

*Заново **драенная** палуба стала еще чище.*

**Орфографический словарь:**

***драеный***, прил.

***драенный;*** кр. ф. -ен, -ена, прич.

**ДРАИТЬ**, драю, драишь; нсв. [от голл. draaien - вертеть]. (нсв. надраить). Разг. Мор. 1. что. Чистить, натирать до блеска. Д. палубу. Д. медные части судна. 2. что. Тщательно чистить, мыть. Д. мелом пуговицы. Д. квартиру до блеска. Боец драит свой автомат.

Answer (score 2):

Прилагательное пишется с одним «н»: ***[драеный](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9)***;

причастие — с двумя «н»: ***[драенный](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9)***.

Без зависимых слов нужно написание с одним «н»:

***драеная палуба***.